# Rails 4 - How to make a callback work only the first time a checkbox is clicked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, callback

How to make a callback work only the first time a checkbox is clicked?

A "quote" model has a checkbox for approved by client. This initiates a callback that generates an invoice. However each time I check and uncheck the box the callback is initiated each time creating duplicate invoices each time. How can I avoid this?
code:

`Class Quote<ActiveRecord::Base
after_save :generate_invoice
def generate_invoice
  Invoice.create!(date: self.date, quantity: self.quantity, unit_cost: self.unit_cost)
end`

Comment: Can you update your code with callback.

Comment: Done, I've update the post with the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you accepted answer. But don't know why you need this extra column. You can do it without invoiced_at column in two ways.

1. Check either invoice present for quote or not. You scenario suggest you should have `has_one` and `belongs_to` relation present in your quote and invoice model.
   So change your code like this.

   ```
   def generate_invoice
     if self.invoice.present?
       Invoice.create!(date: self.date, quantity: self.quantity, unit_cost: self.unit_cost)
     end
   end
   ```
2. Check for created_at and updated_at column in your `Quote` model. For first time they hold same values. So you can change your code like this also.

   ```
   def generate_invoice
     if created_at == updated_at
       Invoice.create!(date: self.date, quantity: self.quantity, unit_cost: self.unit_cost)
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 3):

On first callback set invoiced_at, then in all callbacks only invoice if invoiced_at is not present

```
def generate_invoice
  if self.invoiced_at.blank?
    Invoice.create!(date: self.date, quantity: self.quantity, unit_cost: self.unit_cost)
    self.invoiced_at = Time.now
    self.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please explain further? I am not sure what you mean. Im new to rails. Thank you

Comment: I updated it for you. Add an invoiced_at column to Quote.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
class Quote < ...
  after_save :generate_invoice, if: Proc.new { |q| q.checked.nil? }
```

or using `after_create` if it's created when user click checkbox the first time

Comment: Does the proc need and "end" keyword?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do. In the create action, you wrap your login in an `! Invoice.find_by()` with the parameters from the request. If it already exists, do nothing.

On the front-end, you should really attach some logic to the callback that will remove that checkbox upon check. It's not good convention to have form elements visible on the page that do nothing, or to have form elements that behave differently depending on how many times you've clicked them. Removing the checkbox will make it clear to the user that the invoice was created and they can't take any further action.

Edit: someone asked for specifics on the javascript. What you could do is just disable the form element on click. (Looks nice and gets the point across.) This snippet will disable ever checkbox on the page, so if you want to only disable a certain class of checkbox, you would just replace input[type=checkbox] with the class of the checkbox you want to disable.

`$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function(){$(this).attr("disabled", "true")})`

Comment: What would be the code to achieve the hiding of the checkbox after clicking in the front end? I am very new to rails.

Comment: @davefogo I added the code. This assumes jQuery, which should be installed by default in every new rails app.

Comment: @ Dan Ruswick am trying to implement the code directly in the view via the <script> tag with no success. Am I doing it correctly?